# How to get specific time frame images from video files in Android?

Tags: android, video, time, frame

Actually I need to get the specific time frame images from video using Mediameatdatareteriver
but I'm not interested in using FFMPEG.

If someone have any idea about thisplease help me guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (extracted from Android's `android.media.ThumbnailUtils` class).

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(filePath);
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt video file
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        // Assume this is a corrupt video file.
    } finally {
        try {
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // Ignore failures while cleaning up.
        }
    }
```

Be mindful that the `time` value is in microseconds.

**EDIT** These is [another overload for getFrameAtTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html#getFrameAtTime%28long,%20int%29) where you can pass in options so that the selected frame is closer to the specified time (though it may not be a key frame). For example, use:

```
bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(time, MediaMetadataRetriever. OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

The documentation states that the performance cost of this option is greater though, so be mindful of that.

Comment: Sir now my problem was the frames from video is repeating the first frame images for number of times i've set all type of getFrameAtTime(options) changed from millisec to micro then from micro to millisec but it remains the same can you guide me to solve this problem by your samples.

Comment: @user3627866 Edited the answer, hope it's helpful.

Comment: Actually Sir i used all the option of getFrameAtTime(options)i don't know where it goes wrong not even any error in my Logcat.